# Difference between ListAssets and SearchAllResources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-asset-inventory

I'm trying to list every resource in a given Google Cloud project.

I was using the [`SearchAllResources`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.asset.v1#google.cloud.asset.v1.AssetService.SearchAllResources) endpoint so far.
I'm now struggling to list `cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction` resources.

This resource is supported by the search according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types)

By digging around I've found the [`ListAssets`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.asset.v1#google.cloud.asset.v1.AssetService.ListAssets) endpoint that seems to return cloud functions:

```sh
# This one returned one result
➜ gcloud asset list --project=my-project --asset-types cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction | grep assetType    
assetType: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction

# No result here, even after waiting a couple of hours
➜ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/cloudskiff-dev-elie --asset-types cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction | grep assetType 
Listed 0 items.
```

I also tried without filter on asset types but it does not change the problem, cloud functions resources are not returned by the search all endpoint. I have several difference when I compare the two outputs: [diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Hyn.png)

That's not clear for me what are the purpose of these two endpoints.
I can't find any clarification in GCP documentation. Also I don't get why we do not retrieve same set of resources. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have result without the GREP?

Comment: Actually the ` | grep` is here only to have a more understandable output, this is not a grep issue. I have the same behavior with gRPC calls and CLI

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.asset.v1#google.cloud.asset.v1.AssetService.SearchAllResources), to use `SearchAllResources`: _"The caller must be granted the cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources permission on the desired scope"_

Could you please check you have this permission in the project you're searching?

I've made a test on my project and both returns the same result.

Comment: @RogelioMonter It does not change anything for me. Account used here has owner role on the whole project. I added `Cloud Asset Owner` but I have the same results. I also have the same behavior with `bigtableadmin.googleapis.com/Table`. https://imgur.com/a/9Y8sxCp

Comment: @stanmarsh Could you please confirm if you got any result from the command `search-all-resources`? You've mentioned that you _even after waiting a couple of hours_ got zero results, are you referring that you waited too much time for the command to be completed? Did the command completed successfully or you have to abort it?

Comment: @RogelioMonter By waiting a couple of hours I mean a couple of hours between two gloud cmd execution. To be clear the command exited quickly with success with no results.